# Как создать содержимое и передать в файле xml на sftp?

Tags: php, ssh

Пытаюсь создать и передать файл xml c содержимым через SSH
Пробовал через curl,при этом файл создается на sftp но с пустым содержимым.
Сам код:

```
$xm = "test text";    
$ch = curl_init();
$file = $xm;
$remotefile = 'report-01.xml';
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');
fwrite($fp,$file);   
fclose($fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'sftp://login:pass@adressserver/1/'.$remotefile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file);
curl_exec ($ch);
$error_no = curl_errno($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
if ($error_no == 0) {
$error = 'File uploaded succesfully.';
} else {
$error = 'File upload error.';
}
```

Второй вариант я пробовал так, но файл вообще не передавало.
код:

```
$copycheck="c;";
$text=$copycheck;
$fp = fopen ("ssh2.sftp://login:pass@adressserver/1/filename.xml", "w");   
fwrite($fp,$text);   
fclose($fp);
```

Подскажите где я допустил ошибку, или возможно есть еще варианты.

Comment: Первый ваш вариант вполне рабочий, только у вас в нем ошибка - использование неинициализированной переменной ```$localfile``` 
 в качестве первого аргумента функции ```fopen()```

Comment: Отредактировал в своем вопросе, но так все равно пустой файл

Comment: У вас ```$file``` должен содержать название файла(и полный путь до него) на диске. У вас же он содержит строку(из переменной $xm): ```test text```. Исправьте

Comment: Дело в том что файла то нет, я его пытаюсь в коде и сгенерировать, вернее содержимое.

Comment: @ Max Darkleviathan, извиняюсь. Смотрите мой ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант с использованием временного файла:

```
<?php
$xm = "test text";
$file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "foo");
file_put_contents($file, $xm);
$ch = curl_init();
$remotefile = 'report-01.xml';
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'sftp://login:pass@adressserver/1/'.$remotefile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_exec ($ch);
fclose($fp);
unlink($file);
$error_no = curl_errno($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
if ($error_no == 0) {
$error = 'File uploaded succesfully.';
} else {
$error = 'File upload error.';
}
echo $error;
```

Comment: Да, так действительно работает, я до такого не додумался. Огромнейшее вам спасибо)